# Download Microstrategy Dossiers in .mstr format with Python

Tags: python, business-intelligence, microstrategy

I'am searching for downloading Microstrategy Dossiers as in ".mstr" file format with python. I could not find any online source to do it.

- I have tried "requests" and "mstrio-py" libraries, but those does not seems to be working.
- There is a function called "export_document_to_mstr" in mstrio.project_objects.document in Document. That requires "body" in json format and "instance_id" which I could not find.

I wonder if is there anyone give me ideas ?

Thanks a lot in advanced !

Comment: https://community.microstrategy.com/s/article/Python-script-that-gathers-information-about-datasets-added-to-dossiers-dataset-type-and-location?language=en_US

Comment: Yeah, I've visited this page but that is not cover 'instance_id' and body. Also there is no info about downloading as .mstr file